# Build hierarchical view from object in react native & coffeescript

Tags: react-native, coffeescript

I want to build a view from a hierarchical object in React native with Coffeescript, but i keep only getting the child values as a result.

Consider the following object in my constructor

```
this.state = 
  data: [
    {
      name: 'Category 1'
      projects: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Project 1'
        },{
          id: 2,
          name: 'Project 2'
        }
      ]
    },{
      name: 'Category 2'
      projects: [
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Project 3'
        },{
          id: 4,
          name: 'Project 4'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

From this object i want to build a straightforward view (something) like

```
<View>
  <Text>Category 1</Text>
</View>
<View>
  <Text>Project 1</Text>
</View>
<View>
  <Text>Project 2</Text>
</View>
<View>
  <Text>Category 2</Text>
</View>
<View>
  <Text>Project 3</Text>
</View>
<View>
  <Text>Project 4</Text>
</View>
```

The closest i got to a result is with the following nested loops

```
<View>
  { this.state.data.map( ( category ) =>
    <View><Text>{category.name}</Text></View>
    category.projects.map( ( project ) =>
      <View><Text>{project.name}</Text></View>
    )
  ) }
</View>
```

This however only renders the projects (without the categories).

What am i missing here? I have the feeling it's something pretty obvious, but i can't see it (anymore)

**EDIT:**
Although @mjabadilla solution works in JSX i couldn't convert it to Coffeescript so i changed the object structure and make it work that way

```
this.state = 
  {
    data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Category 1'
        type: 'Category'
      },{
        id: 2, 
        name: 'Project 1'
        type: 'Project'
      },{
        id: 3
        name: 'Project 2'
        type: 'Project'
      },{
        id: 4
        name: 'Category 2'
        type: 'Category'
      },{
        id: 5
        name: 'Project 3'
        type: 'Project'
      },{
        id: 6
        name: 'Project 4'
        type: 'Project'
      }
    ]
  }

  { this.state.data.map( ( prop ) =>
    if prop.type == 'category'
      <View><Text>Category: {prop.name}</Text></View>
    else
      <View><Text>Project: {prop.name}</Text></View>
  ) }
```

Not as clean as the initial approach, but at least it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that multiline is returned explicitly. See the code on my snack example. You have to convert it to CoffeeScript

https://snack.expo.io/BkBS3vQhG

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      { this.state.data.map( ( category ) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>{category.name}</Text>

            {category.projects.map( ( project ) => (
              <View>
                <Text>{project.name}</Text>
              </View>))}
            </View>
         )
     })}
    </View>
);
```

}

Comment: You're jsx solution works, but i somehow can't get it converted to coffeescript. I managed to achieve what i want in another way so it's working in the end. Thnx